# 'depend strongly' or 'strongly depend'

Tags: adverbs

I have the following sentence:

"The improvements are on average 5 % and **depend strongly** on the price difference".

Would you rather use 'strongly depend' in this case? I read on a German website that the adverb should come after the object (https://www.ego4u.de/de/cram-up/grammar/word-order/adverb-position, example"He    drove   the car carefully"). This does not make any sense to me as the sentence would be:
"The improvements are on average 5 % and **depend** on the price difference **strongly**".

Comment: You have choices, even "depend strongly on price..." For parallelism, I like "*are* X... and *depend* strongly..."

Comment: Thanks for your comment Yosef Baskin. So I can write 'strongly depend'?

Comment: Yes, the choices make for slight differences in emphasis.

Comment: 'Depend strongly' would be seen more commonly, IMO. Though [these Google 3-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=depend+strongly+on%2Cstrongly+depend+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdepend%20strongly%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrongly%20depend%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdepend%20strongly%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrongly%20depend%20on%3B%2Cc0) seem to indicate I may need to shift allegiance shortly. Shortly shift allegiance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Or maybe you'll shortly need to shift allegiance.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Stop calling me _Shortly_.